# Center A form HTML CSS

Tags: html, css

Hello I am having issues centering a form for a login page. I am not to good with CSS and it has been a while since I have played with HTML. What I want to do is, center the input boxes and align the text left on top of the input fields, as well as have an image centered as well, like in the picture. I have tried adding different div id and tags to the form but I can not seem to figure out the css part. I appreciate any help and sorry if the CSS is sloppy.

[image]

```css
body {
    background-color:lightgray; 
    font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;  
}
h1 {
    color: black;
}
p {
    color: black;
}

html {
    text-alight: center;
}

#login {
    text-align:center; 
}

input[type=text], input[type=date], input[type=password] {
    width: 30%;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

input[type=submit] {
    width: 30%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#service_type, #series, #speaker, #users {
    width: 30%;
    height: 50px;   
}

@media only screen and (max-device-width: 1024px){

input[type=text], input[type=date], input[type=password] {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

input[type=submit] {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#service_type, #series, #speaker, #users{
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
}

#keypad_users{
    width: 345px;
    height: 50px;
    vertical-align:middle; 
    text-align:center;
    border:1px solid #000000; 
    font-size:30px; 
    font-weight:bold;
}

#keypad {margin:auto; margin-top:10px;}

#keypad tr td {
    vertical-align:middle; 
    text-align:center; 
    border:1px solid #000000; 
    font-size:18px; 
    font-weight:bold; 
    width:100px; 
    height:80px; 
    cursor:pointer; 
    background-color:#666666; 
    color:#CCCCCC;
}

#keypad tr td:hover {
background-color:#999999; 
color:#FFFF00;
}

#display {
text-align:center; 
    width:345px; 
    margin:10px auto auto auto; 
    background-color:#000000; 
    color:#00FF00; 
    font-size:48px; 
    border:1px solid #999999;
}
#message {
    text-align:center; 
    color:#009900; 
    font-size:18px; 
    font-weight:bold; 
    display:none;
}

}
```

```html
<div id="login">
<form action = "login.php" id="login" method ="POST">
Username <br />
<input type="text" name="username" id="username" required /><br /><br />
Password <br />
<input type ="password" name="password" id="password" required /><br /><br />

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Log in">

</form> 
</div>
```

Comment: It is not clear from your code how you are placing your image.

Comment: The image code has not been inputted yet, sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've improved your HTML. All form inputs should have an associated [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label) element. Also don't use `br` for spacing use padding/margin instead.

Further more use have a duplicated `id`, id's must be unique to the page.

```css
#login_container  /*This is Our base container for the login "control" */
{
  width:30%; /*Define the width of the control*/
  margin:auto; /*This Provide the horizontal centering of the control*/
  padding:120px 10px 10px 10px; /*Add some padding, the first number is the top and provides room for the image*/
  background-image:url(" http://fillmurray.com/100/100"); /*Add our background image, thanks Bill Murray*/
  background-position:center 10px; /*Position our image, first is Horizontal alignment, second is top*/
  background-repeat:no-repeat; /*One Bil Murray is more than enough*/
  background-color: #F0F0F0; /*Base Background image*/
}

#login_container label
{
  display:block;  /*Label will now take up a whole line*/
  margin-bottom:.25em; /*Give it some room underneath*/
}

#login_container input[type="text"], #login_container input[type="password"], #login_container input[type="submit"]
{
  width:100%; /*Form controls now take 100% width of the container*/
  margin-bottom:0.5em;
}
```

```html
<div id="login_container"> <!-- Can't have duplicate ID's -->
<form action = "login.php" id="login" method ="POST">
   <label for="username">Username </label>
   <input type="text" name="username" id="username" required />
   <label for="password">Password</label>
   <input type ="password" name="password" id="password" required />
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Log in">
</form> 
</div>
```

Comment: I did not mean to use the same id for the form and div, I forgot to take that out when I was trying out code to make it work. so instead of a div tag could I use the form id tag, and will it do the same thing if I choose to remove one of them?

Comment: I am using chome, I got it to work, but adding a text-align tag in #login_container label

Comment: Yes you could remove the `div`. Just change the selectors to the form id.

Comment: Well thank you, you got the answer that I was looking for. If I may make one request, can you explain the code a little bit and how it got it to work, and why I could not get it to align left ?

Comment: I'll flesh out the answer to explain the code a bit more. The issue with aligning may have been due to other CSS on your page with it's own align.

Comment: `background-repeat:no-repeat;` https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/background-repeat,  you may also want to investigate https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size and then do a little research on CSS Sprites.

Comment: Thank you again, at this point I think I have what I need. You are awesome!!

Answer (score 3):

I've made a JSfiddle for you [here (click me please)](https://jsfiddle.net/gay1ufa1/1/) that resembles the picture you've added.

As requested to not use a third party like I've added the code here:

HTML

```
<div id="login">
  <form action = "login.php" id="login" method ="POST">
    <div class="picture">

    </div>
    <p>Username</p>
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" required /><br /><br />
    
    <p>Password</p>
    <input type ="password" name="password" id="password" required /><br /><br />

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Log in">
  </form> 
</div>
```

CSS

```
body
{
    background-color:lightgray; 
    font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;  
}

#login
{
    text-align:center;
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.picture
{
  width:100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  background-color:red;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#login p
{
  float: left;
}
input[type=text], input[type=date], input[type=password] {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

input[type=submit] {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

**EDIT:**
New fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/gay1ufa1/2/

Comment: thank you, but now the page looks funky, The text, is shifted to the very left of the page. I am sorry if I was not clear on the question, I do not want the login input  to go all the way across the page, but have it 30%, have the label or p tages to be the left of the input boxes.

Comment: Then I would suggest to alter the width of the login id, did you mean something like this? I've changed the fiddle for you: https://jsfiddle.net/gay1ufa1/2/

Comment: Yes like that, but is there anyway of doing it without setting the input[type=text] to 100% and leaving it at the original 30%?

Comment: @Wanjia You are required to provide your solution here and not a third party site which can change or disappear tomorrow helping no one.

Comment: @Rob I've changed the answer & Vlad The 100% width for the input doesn't need to be there but you can play around with the values to meet what you have in mind but if you want the full form to be at 30% change it in at #login

Comment: Thank you, but do I have to set the input[type=text], input[type=date], input[type=password] , width: 100%; or can I still keep my 30%?

Comment: You can keep it the way you want. But if you are going to make everything within the form 30%, change the width for the parent (#login in this case) as it is shorter and easier to understand the code.

Answer (score 1):

One problem in your code is that you use the ID "login " twice, which must not be done. I put together a codepen, which you can find here:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dNWQgp

What I basically did (except adding a div representing the image in your picture): I assigned the following CSS to a wrapper DIV around the whole form and image. It uses flexbox to center the contents. Plus I assigned a `width` setting (40%) to the `form` element.

```
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Comment: I always forget flexbox, and it's alway worth a mention when it comes to centering.

Answer (score 0):

To center a `div` set `margin-left` and `margin-right` to `auto` and assign a fixed `width` to it. In your case, this would be for `#login`.

Comment: #login {
     text-align: center; 
     margin-left: auto;
     margin-right: auto;
     width: 250px;
    } Here is what I did, and still not centered

Answer (score 0):

Minimal jump start template, using CSS flex:

```css
body {background:darkblue;margin:0;min-height:100vh;display:flex;align-items:center;justify-content:space-around;font-size:large}
#container {width:30%;margin:auto;padding:2em;background-color:#F0F0F0;border-radius: 0.5em}
#container input {margin:0.5em 0 1em 0;height: 2em;padding: 0.5em;width:calc(100% - 1.5em);font-weight:bold}
#container input[type="submit"] {cursor:pointer;font-size:larger;margin:0.5em 0 0 0;padding:0.2em;width:100%}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset=utf-8>
<title>Login</title>
<body>
  <div id="container">
    <form action = "login.php" id="login" method ="POST">
       <label for="username">Username </label>
       <input type="text" name="username" id="username" required />
       <label for="password">Password</label>
       <input type ="password" name="password" id="password" required />
       <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Log in">
    </form>
  </div>
</body></html>
```

---

Going a bit further in the CSS, while keeping it fairly minimal. The emoji icon is a Unicode character, taken from Unicode 15.1 https://www.unicode.org/emoji/charts-15.1/emoji-style.txt

```css
body {background:darkblue;margin:0;min-height:100vh;display:flex;align-items:center;justify-content:space-around;font-size:large}
.logo {
  height: 7em;
  max-height: 7em;
  max-width: 7em;
  background: #272b2d;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 100 100'><text y='0.8em' font-size='100'>‍♂️</text></svg>");
  background-size: cover;
  border-radius: 7em;
  border: 0.5em deepskyblue solid;
  transition: transform .7s ease-in-out;
  margin: 0 auto 1em auto
}
.logo:hover {transform: rotate(360deg);cursor:crosshair}
#container {width:12em;margin:auto;padding:2em;background-color:#F0F0F0;border-radius: 0.5em;min-width:12em;max-width:12em;transition: all 0.5s ease-in}
#container:hover {box-shadow: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3) 0px 0px 50px}
#container input {margin:0.5em 0 1em 0;height: 2em;padding: 0.5em;width:calc(100% - 1.5em);font-weight: bold}
#container input[type="submit"] {cursor:pointer;font-size:larger;margin:0.5em 0 0 0;padding:0.2em;width:100%}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset=utf-8>
<title>DB</title>
<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div class="logo"></div>
    <form action = "login.php" id="login" method ="POST">
       <label for="username">Username </label>
       <input type="text" name="username" id="username" required />
       <label for="password">Password</label>
       <input type ="password" name="password" id="password" required />
       <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Log in">
       <br><br>
       <a href="#">Register account</a>
    </form>
  </div>
</body></html>
```

[image]